# Android 4.0 kernel source code?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, android-kernel

Where can I get the Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) ***kernel*** source code?

While this might be a stupid question that some people have asked before, *I can't seem to find a suitable answer anywhere* because:

- Google decided to be really useful and redirect `android.kernel.org` to `http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html`, which includes every single part of Android **apart from the kernel**. *I do not understand the logic behind that.*
- `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git` does something weird and creates a massive *(600 MB+)* `.git` folder without creating the source tree. I don't give two shits about the git repo, **I just need the source tree**.
- All the kernel forks on GitHub are horribly outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Watch the android source code hosted on **[Github](https://github.com/android)**.

Answer (score 9):

In his Nov 30, 2011 [post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/msg/646730c7d4e143bc), Jean-Baptiste Queru explains why the kernel source is invisible after cloning. [This post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/msg/ff4e97808535b396) describes the kernel source branches that exist for the various hardware flavors of ICS.

And in general, here's how to make a specific branch visible:

```bash
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git # clone the repo
git branch -a # lists branches, both local and remote
git checkout -b android-3.0 remotes/origin/android-3.0 # create local branch
# android-3.0 that tracks the named remote branch
```